# Оператор преобразования при передаче интерфейса объекта

Tags: c#, .net, перегрузка-операторов

Я не понимаю почему я не могу предавать тип интерфейса как тип объекта, даже если тип унаследован от этого интерфейса?

Т.е.:

```
public interface ICObject : IDisposable
{
    IntPtr CObjectPtr { get; }
    bool IsDisposed { get; }
    bool IsInvalid { get; }
}
```

Далее определение базового абстрактного класса:

```
public abstract class CObject : ICObject
{
    ...

    public static implicit operator IntPtr(CObject currentObject)
    {
        return currentObject.CObjectPtr;
    }
}
```

А теперь, если я буду передавать интерфейс в метод который принимает `IntPtr` вместо самого объекта, я не смогу применить оператор преобразования

```
public static implicit operator IntPtr(CObject currentObject)
{ ... }
```

Если от этого лекарство или может можно перегрузить оператор?

Comment: *если я буду передавать интерфейс в метод который принимает IntPtr вместо самого объекта, я не смогу применить оператор преобразования* — ну вроде логично

Comment: Почему просто не сделать класс-конвертер из одного типа в другой и не передавать его?

Comment: Либо сделать метод расширение для интерфейса и использовать его

Comment: Я передаю `CObject`, однако, приходится делать каст от интерфейса, к классу... Это не особо меня беспокоит. однако было интересно почему так нельзя делать.

Comment: Судя по описанию, вы предаете ICObject, логично что компилятор не может преобразовать его в IntPtr, такого оператора нет